# OData controller doesn't return derived object

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, odata, xml-deserialization

I have these classes

```
public class Control
{
public int ukey {get; set;}
public string ControlName {get; set;}
public string ControlType {get; set;}
public string Property {get; set;}
}

[DataContract]
[Serializable]
public class DeserializedProperty: Control
{
[DataMember]
public object DeserializedProp {get; set;}
}
```

In the `Control` class, the member `Property` is a XML string. The XML is different for each control based on the control type.

I want to query the database, get all the controls, deserialize the property to an object and return it. This is how my GET method looks like:

```
public class OData_ControlsController : ODataController
{
[Queryable]
public HttpResponseMessage Get([FromODataUri] int id)
{
List<DeserializedProperty> deserializedSteps = new List<DeserializedProperty>();

var controls = getAllControls(id);//returns all control
foreach(var control in controls)
{
     DeserializedProperty prop = new DeserializedProperty();
     prop.DeserializedProp = _deserialize(control.Property);
     deserializedSteps.Add(prop);
}

return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, deserializedSteps);
}
}
```

`_deserialize` method deserializes the XML correctly. On the `return` line, the `deserializedSteps` has the base class (`Control`) and derived class (`DeserializedProperty`) but when I get the response in the client it doesn't have `DeserializedProp` object in the JSON. The response only has the base class property.

How can I return `DeserializedProperty (Control + DeserializedProp)`?

Comment: How does _deserialize method looks like?

Comment: Can you try `var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All };` and pass back this settings to serialize method as argument.See example here http://gigi.nullneuron.net/gigilabs/deserializing-derived-types-with-json-net/